# Why does hitting enter in Visual Editor add <p> instead of <br>?

Tags: html, visual-editor

Why does hitting the enter key in Visual Editor add `<p>` instead of `<br>`?

What I want sometimes is a new line that starts immediately after the previous line. Unfortunately, the visual editor automatically wraps my new line in a `<p>` tag when all I really want is a `<br>` tag so that there is no space between the two lines.

How can I solve this without specifically changing my code in the HTML tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit `Shift + Enter` and you''ll get `<br>`

Comment: I'm not really sure why you think that would work. I gave it a shot and all it did was put extra space after each paragraph. This is not what I want. What I want is to have no space after a line break.

Comment: I get it. Edited the answer.

Comment: Haha, there it is. Well, almost. CTRL + Enter didn't work for me. I gave Shift + Enter a try and that did the trick!

Comment: of course `Shift + Enter`. It was my mistake, need some sleep :)